# Prove that the number of free variables in the system $\bf Ax = O$ is equal to the nullity of the matrix $\bf A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, proof-writing

> **Proposition** The number of free variables in the system $\bf Ax = O$ is equal to
>   the nullity of the matrix $\bf A$.

My attempt:

I'll break it into two parts:

1. Consider case where linear system has no free variables.
2. Consider case where there is at least one free variable.

**1.**

Suppose system $\bf Ax = O$ has no free variables. Let $\mathbf R = rref(A)$. Each column of $\bf R$ will have leading one. Then linear system $\bf Rx = O$ will have a unique solution ($\bf x = O$). Since $\bf Ax = O$ is equivalent to $\bf Rx = O$, linear system  $\bf Ax = O$ will also have a unique solution. Null space of $\bf A$ only contains zero vector. Hence $\text{nullity} = 0$.

**2.**

Consider arbitrary matrix $\bf A$ with $n$ columns, such that $\bf Ax = O$ has $m$ free variables. Let $\mathbf R = rref(A)$. $m$ columns of $\bf R$ will not have leading one (to simplify matters, let's suppose that all columns with no leading one are located to the right of the matrix). Hence arbitrary vector $\bf x$ which satisfy $\bf Rx = O$ will have $m$ entries that can take on any value (free variable), and the remaining $n-m$ entries (pivot variables) can be rewritten as the linear combination of the free variables. In other words

$$\mathbf{x} = \begin {pmatrix}
k_{1,1}s_1 +   k_{1,2}s_2 + \cdots + k_{1,m}s_m \\
k_{2,1}s_1 +   k_{2,2}s_2 + \cdots + k_{2,m}s_m \\
\vdots \\
k_{n-m,1}s_1 +   k_{n-m,2}s_2 + \cdots + k_{n-m,m}s_m \\
s_1 \\
s_2 \\
\vdots \\
s_m
\end {pmatrix}
$$

Where $k$'s are constants and $s$'s are free variables.

Vector $\bf x$ can be rewritten as the following vectors

$$s_{1} \begin {pmatrix}
k_{1,1} \\
k_{2,1} \\
\vdots \\
k_{n-m,1}\\
1 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0 \end {pmatrix} + s_{2} \begin {pmatrix}
k_{1,2} \\
k_{2,2} \\
\vdots \\
k_{n-m,2}\\
0 \\
1 \\
\vdots \\
0 \end {pmatrix} + \cdots + s_{m} \begin {pmatrix}
k_{1,m} \\
k_{2,m} \\
\vdots \\
k_{n-m,m}\\
0 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
1 \end {pmatrix} = s_1\mathbf{v}_1 + s_2\mathbf{v}_2 + \cdots + s_m\mathbf{v}_m$$

It can be see that there are $m$ of them. These $m$ vectors span null space of $\bf A$. Now we are required to show that they are linearly independent.

---

*I suppose you won't like the following part*

---

Consider arbitrary vector $\mathbf{v}_{j}$. The entry of the vector $\mathbf{v}_{j}$  with the index $n-m+j$ will equal to $1$. But the corresponding entries of the remaining vectors are all equal to zero. Therefore, the entry of the vector $\mathbf{v}_j$ with the index $n-m+j$  cannot be rewritten as the linear combination of the entries of remaining vectors, and hence vector *itself* cannot by formed by the linear combination of the other vectors.

In general, for any vector $\mathbf{v}_i$,  the entry with the index $n-m+i$ is not the linear combination of corresponding entries of the remaining vectors.

Therefore, no vector can be rewritten as the linear combination of the remaining vectors. We can conclude that vectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{v}_m$ are linearly independent. Hence dimension of $N(A)$, or nullity, is $m$. $\Box$

---

I have a lot of doubts, but still, is it correct?

I would also like to have a look at the alternatives (but keep in mind that I'm currently studying the book on *introductory* linear algebra, hence I might not be able to understand proofs which involve more complicated concepts.)