# Prove that for any matrix $\bf A$ with $n$ columns, $\operatorname{nullity}(\mathbf{A}) + \operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A}) = n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, matrix-rank

$\DeclareMathOperator{\nullity}{nullity}\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}$

> Theorem (3.34). The dimension theorem of matrices (rank-nullity
>   theorem): If $A$ is a matrix with n columns (number of unknowns) then
>   $$\nullity(\mathbf{A}) + \rank(\mathbf{A}) = n$$

My attempt:

Consider arbitrary matrix $\bf A$ with $n$ columns.

---

Let $\mathbf R = \operatorname{rref}(\mathbf A)$. Suppose $\rank(\mathbf A) = n$. It follows that $\bf R$ won't have columns without leading ones. Hence the only vector $\bf x$ that satisfies $\bf Rx = O$  is zero vector. Since $\bf Rx = O$ is equivalent to $\bf Ax = O$, solution set must be the same. And that means that null space of $\bf A$ consists of a single vector, $\bf O$. Hence $\nullity(\mathbf{A}) = 0$

We have $\rank(\mathbf A)  + \nullity(\mathbf{A}) = n + 0 = n$

---

Let $\mathbf R = \operatorname{rref}(\mathbf A)$. Suppose $\rank(\mathbf{A}) = m$ where $m < n$. It implies that the linear system $\bf Rx = O$ will have $n-m$ free variables. Since $\bf Rx = O$ is equivalent $\bf Ax = O$, then $\bf Ax = O$ will have $n-m$ free variables too. And because number of free variables equals to nullity of the $\bf A$ (I tried to prove this proposition [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3381276/prove-that-the-number-of-free-variables-in-the-system-bf-ax-o-is-equal-to-t)), it follows that $\nullity(\mathbf A) = n-m$

We have 
$$\rank(\mathbf{A}) + \nullity(\mathbf{A}) = m + n - m = n$$
$\Box$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct. It also looks like you don't need to consider the case where the rank is $n$ separately.